# SIP Sever on Amazon EC2 Server

Tags: sip

I am making a voice call Android application and trying to use Amazon EC2 as SIP server. Amazon EC2 server is slightly slow where I live. It makes about 0.05 ~ 0.1 second delay compare to local server.

I know that SIP server helps to register SIP address and let users know the SIP address. It looks like speed of Internet broadband makes delay when users make a call.

The question is that does SIP voice chat quality matter on speed of SIP server network?

Comment: This question is off topic for SO, however you may want to look at [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/about).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No the latency of the SIP connections will not affect the media quality provided you build your application so that the SIP signalling and RTP media are separate and the RTP media is transmitted directly between the call end points.

SIP was designed with the intention of having the media be transmitted directly between the call end points but because of NAT most SIP servers will proxy the media. If you are using a SIP server like OpenSIPS or Kamailio WITHOUT the rtpproxy then the media will be direct and the network delay to your SIP server will not affect the call media.